# Text Box Concatenation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, concatenation

I'm trying to get the code to work before the 7th textbox is added and once it has been added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Concatenate Words</title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNew()
        {
            document.getElementById("newBut").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='tb7'>";
        }

    function concatenate()
        {
            concateText = document.getElementById("tb1").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb2").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb3").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb4").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb5").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb6").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb7").value;

            document.getElementById("concateForm").value = concateText;
        }


</script>
    <h1>Please enter text into the fields below</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb4">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb5">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb6">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="newBut">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="textResult" id="concateForm" value="" onkeyup="concatenate()">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="Add A New Box" value="Add an extra field" onclick="addNew()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The problem that i am having is that the code only works once the 7th text box has been added by clicking the button at the bottom. I was wondering whether it is possible to get the same function to work without the extra box added into the html code.

Comment: Check if the input exists before referencing it?

Comment: How would you go about doing this? i tried to do document.getElementById("tb7).value == ""; whilst using an if statement in the function but it didn't work for me

Comment: @Bevvy check that with a ternary operator like my answer

Comment: Thank you all for the help, @jafarbtech answer helped me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it with a condition to check whether `tb7` is available. like

```
((document.getElementById("tb7"))? " " + document.getElementById("tb7").value:"")
```

Because `tb7` is not there in the DOM before you press `add new` button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Concatenate Words</title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNew()
        {
            document.getElementById("newBut").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='tb7'>";
        }

    function concatenate()
        {
            concateText = document.getElementById("tb1").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb2").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb3").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb4").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb5").value + " " + document.getElementById("tb6").value + ((document.getElementById("tb7"))? " " + document.getElementById("tb7").value:"");

            document.getElementById("concateForm").value = concateText;
        }


</script>
    <h1>Please enter text into the fields below</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb4">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb5">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tb6">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="newBut">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="textResult" id="concateForm" value="" onkeyup="concatenate()">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="Add A New Box" value="Add an extra field" onclick="addNew()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. Does the ((document.getElementById("tb7"))? " "  basically check if tb7 exists then?

Comment: yaah... it checks whether it exists

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a concrete selector of the tb7 box, this will throw an exception when attempting to get the value. This is why you need the 7th to before a result will show. You would be better off making this dynamic by using [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and enumerating through the list to perform your concatenation.

As an alternative, this could be made remarkable simple by switching to jQuery and using selectors and the [.each() function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Sample:

```
function addNew()
{
    document.getElementById("newBut").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='tb7' class='concatInput'>";
}

function concatenate()
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("concatInput");
    var concatText = "";
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        concatText += elements[i].value;
    }
    document.getElementById("concateForm").value = concateText;
}
```

Comment: Just one thing: concatText += elements[i].value;

Comment: Thank you for your help, haven't really looked into jQuery as of yet... maybe in the future

Comment: @sinisake: Thanks, I had that in my brain, but typing at work in notepad I just spaced on it.

Answer (score 0):

add class to all textboxes
example:

```
<input type="text" class="tb" id="tb1">
<input type="text" class="tb" id="tb2">
```

then

```
var text = "";
document.querySelectorAll('.tb').forEach(function() { 
text = text + " " + $(this).val();
 });
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is the element may not be there. So check for its existence beofre referencing the value.

```
var inp7 = document.getElementById("tb7");
var str = inp7 ? inp7.value : "";
```